# c# 2D Array inside a Struct

Tags: c#, arrays, struct

I need to return a struct from a method. One of the members of the struct needs to be a 2D array. I am aware of using fixed size buffers to declare the size of the array in the struct and of using

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct struct1
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
       ....
}
```

but here is the issue. I cannot do this as I do not know the length of the array ahead of time. The size of the array depends on parameters chosen by the user at runtime.

```
struct foo {
    int x;
    double[,]  A = new double[N, M];
};
```

I do not know N or M ahead of time. They are selected by the user at runtime.

Is this possible? If yes, how would one do it? Thank you in advance for any suggestions or advice you may be able to provide.

Comment: Is there any reason why you cannot use a Class?

Comment: This is part of larger code. Don't want the overhead. Also, structs are passed by reference and not by value. (I think). Stack vs heap issues as well.

Comment: Classes are also passed by reference.

Comment: If the overhead of using a class over a struct here will have significant impact on your system then your system has significant design issues.  C# is designed to optimize and use classes well... use the language, this isn't c++.  Don't pre-optimize

Comment: Part of the issue also is that the memebers of the struct are all data types. There are no methods. Finally, I am also not really sure how one would do it using classes. Also, the struct is completely updated on every set of data processed.

Comment: Neither classes nor structs are passed by reference, everything is passed by value.

Comment: The struct is being returned from the method as either ref or out. Have not decided yet.

Comment: Okay, I was not aware of this. When using out or ref parameters both, classes and structs, are obviously passed by reference. Why do you want to do this? Is the return value already used for something different?

Comment: The return value will be used for further processing. This is just the first step and further processing requires the value returned.

Comment: Does it have to be an array? You could try using lists instead.

Comment: The method returning it generates it as an array. I suppose it could be converted from an array to a list but before subsequent processing it would need to be returned to an array form. So I prefer not to use lists.

Comment: To make a long story short, it is not possible. Structs must have a fixed size, period. You could of course define the array size to be the worst case, that is the maximum, size. This will waste space if the required array size is smaller and you will probably have to provide some helper methods to make working with this type simpler. As a side note I am still not convinced that a struct would be good choice even if possible. There will be a noticeable performance impact due to passing large structs by value and the associated value type semantics is a good fit for relatively few things.

Comment: Then what would you suggest? If not a struct then what, and how would I do it?

Comment: Either use a struct with a reference to the array or a class.

    internal struct Foo
    {
        private Double[,] bar = null;

        internal Foo(Int32 sizeX, Int32 sizeY)
        {
            this.bar = new Double[sizeX, sizeY];
        }
    }

Comment: @DanielBruckner Thank you for your suggestion. Could you please give a small sample of codefor the struct with reference and a class? I am not sure I am following your example properly. Thank you very much.

Comment: The comment already contains the whole type; what else do you need or where does it not fit you requirements?

Comment: I apologize but how do I pass sizeX and sizeY in? I will study your example more closely. Thank you.

Comment: var foo = new Foo(12, 34); and you get a Foo with the field bar pointing to a Double array of size 12 x 34. I am probably misunderstanding you.

Comment: I understand. I have tried to compile and am getting the following error: Cannot have instance field initializers in structs. It is triggered by the line, private Double[,] bar = null; I will work on this. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Ohhh, yes, of course, I did not start Visual Studio to see if I made any mistakes. Just remove the initializer, it will be initialized to null anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to inline a variable sized array because structs must have fixed size known at compile time. You can of course have a reference to an array of a size only known at runtime.

```
internal struct Foo
{
   internal Double[,] bar;

   internal Foo(Int32 sizeX, Int32 sizeY)
   {
     this.bar = new Double[sizeX, sizeY];
   }
}
```

You can use this struct like this

```
private function Foo InitializeFoo(Int32 sizeX, Int32 sizeY)
{
   var foo = new Foo(sizeX, sizeY);

   for (var y = 0; y < sizeY; y++)
   {
      for (var x = 0; x < sizeX; x++)
      {
         foo.bar[x, y] = x * y;
      }
   }

   return foo;
}
```

and calling this method like

```
var foo = InitializeFoo(12, 34);
```

will give you an instance of Foo with the field bar referencing a Double array of dimension 12 x 34.

Comment: This is great thank you. I have reproduced this but get an error on the line: internal double[,] bar = null;; The error states "cannot have instance field initializers in structs."

Comment: See my last comment to the question.

Comment: Am working with it. Still getting errors on inconsistent accessibility level when I pass it as a ref parameter to a method but I think I can work this out.

Comment: I have resolved the accessibility issue but am getting the error: Foo does not contain a definition for bar and no extension method bar accepting a first argument of type Foo could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: That is because `bar` is declared as `private` - you will have to make it visible or probably even better provide a visible property wrapping the field. The inconsistent accessibility is due to the sample code declaring the struct `Foo` as internal and you probably used it in a method with `public` visibility, so again you have to adjust visibility.